# Copying files from an existing directory to a newly mounted disk

Tags: linux, mount

If I add a disk and mount it as a /var/log, then the old contents of /var/log will be hidden and can only be seen when I umount /var/log. Is there any way for me to transfer the existing files to the new mount point? I can create another folder and copy the contents to it, then copy them to the new mount point, but seeing that these are logs, I may miss something in the process.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41337/48603)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your answer you are suggesting a process with two copies:

1. from /var/log to temporary folder
2. from temporary folder to new /var/log

However you can do it in a single copy-process

1. Mount the **new disk** in another place different of `/`, for example mount it on  `/media` so its path will be `/media/var/log`.
2. Do the copy from `/var/log` to `/media/var/log`.
3. After it is finished *unmount* both and **mount the new disk** on `/`.

If you use `cp` don't forget the `-p` **option** that will preserve timestamp and ownership.

Comment: I'm already suggesting this in my question

Comment: I corrected my answer to include your suggestion.